# Table 4x4 springMVC + thymeleat

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Tell me where to look.
We need to make an HTML page with a 4x4 table and populate it from the backend. Also after filling in the table cell and pressing Enter, so that the cell value and its coordinates are sent to the server.
This must be done using Java + Spring MVC. As I understand correctly, thymeleat templates will help with this, but nothing happens. Thank you!